# Magento 1: How to verify local magento on Mage report for patches?

Tags: patches, local, magento1.9.0.1

I am using magento 1.9.0.1 and i have applied some patches on this in my local system. Now, I want to check patches applied successfully or not on [magereport.com](http://magereport.com).

How can i check my local magento on [magereport.com](http://magereport.com)?

**Note:** I know that we can check by looking in  `app/etc/applied.patches.list` but I am applying patches by copy/paste files so these patches details are not available in `app/etc/applied.patches.list`

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: If you are developing using vagrant, you ca do it with vagrant share command
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/share.html

Answer (score 3):

You cannot unless you open the local development server for access from outside.

I'd suggest to create a staging/testing environment on a sub-domain and test that.

Comment: it's very difficult to debug on server environment.  I want for local.